# Why does my drop down navigation menu wrap and drop onto a 2nd line?

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar, word-wrap

I am having trouble getting my drop down navigation menu to work. The main issue is when I zoom out in Google Chrome, the menu starts wrapping and dropping to a 2nd line, causing all other divs on the page to wrap too.

I have searched across the internet to find a solution but nothing seems to work. Thanks for your advice.

Html:

```
 <div id="nav">
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Quality</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Processes</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Markets</a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Products</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Product information</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Product number one submenu</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Product number two submenu</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Product 4</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Product num 5</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Products 6, more & products</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Prod numb Seven</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">More products eight</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">More prods, prods and products</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">prod Stock List</a></li>
   </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
   <li><a href="#">News</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Latest news</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Case Studies</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Directions</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
     #nav {
background-color:#14c64a;
height:37px;
width:960px;
}

   #nav ul {
   font-family: Arial, Verdana;
   font-size: 14px;
   margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
white-space:nowrap;
    }

    #nav ul li {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
       float: left;
     }

    #nav li ul {
    display: none;
    }

    #nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #14c64a;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
line-height:27px;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
background: #666;
}

#nav li:hover ul {
display: block;
position: absolute;
}

#nav li:hover li {
float: none;
font-size: 11px;
}

#nav li:hover a { background: #14c64a; }

#nav li:hover li a:hover {
    background: #1e7c9a;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome doesn't want to shrink its font size below the minimum font size set by the user, even when zooming. That causes the texts to be wider than the `960px` container at some point while zooming out.

(You can test this by making the minimum font size equal to the default font size in the settings. Then Chrome won't shrink the text at all when zooming out, not even a little.)

By the way, here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/Sm42N/) of the code in the question, so people can test instantly.

Comment: You can't apply anything to the code. This is a user setting that is independent of the webpage's styles. All you do is hope that the user won't try to zoom out too far.